# Affix-top not setting back at the right time/position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The script that I have to affix the nav-bar works almost smoothly but it does not float back at the right time.

This is the code that I am using to affix.

```
 $('.floatNav').affix({
    offset: {
        top: function () { return $('.floatNav').height(); }
    }
});
```

I am having the problem to set it back (affix-top) at the right time. This is the code that I have been working with:

```
 $('.floatNav').on('affixed-top.bs.affix', function () {
       return $('.floatNav').height();
});
```

Comment: fyi: javascript != java

Comment: what is `affix()`?

Comment: @DMcCallum83: It is a bootstrap plugin that plugin allows an element to become affixed (locked) to an area on the page. This is often used with navigation menus or social icon buttons, to make them "stick" at a specific area while scrolling up and down the page. For more info: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_js_affix.asp

Comment: @Marvin: lol. Any other ideas that you can throw at it?

Comment: pfff, sounds messier than just doing it yourself :).  Why can't you just use `jQuery's offset()`?  to set it's fixed position?

Comment: I say slap it in a jsfiddle and let's have a play around.  Or if that library isn't available in hosted fiddle-likes, have you got a git repo we can lookk at?

Comment: Not a bad plan.However, I am aiming to make the nav-bar float when a user scrolls past the original position of the nav-bar. The nav-bar stays up-top visible which I have the work done. But setting it back to its original position at the right time has been a pain. Futhermore, I have a collapsible panel (Bootstrap) on top of it; so the script that I have ignores the fact that runs past it and only after that it falls back to its correct state.

Comment: I can certainly do that. @DMcCallum83

Comment: Could a `.scroll()` handle the dynamic position required once it's been displayed?

Comment: That's a great idea. Let me see if I can come up with something.

Comment: That seems be more trickier than I thought :(

Comment: Our dev team used a different approach to get the desired result. We used good old jQuery to show and hide the div panels and got grid of the bootstrap collapse plugin.